# How to set up a Redshift connection with Slick?

Tags: scala, amazon-redshift, slick

I would like to set up a connection on an `Amazon Redshift` instance from `Scala` with `Slick`.

Which driver should I use and how can I set it up with `sbt` and `Slick`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [Amazon's Redshift driver for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html) and include it to the `build.sbt` (see the [release note](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/Amazon+Redshift+JDBC+Release+Notes.pdf) for the current version):

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Redsfhit" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"
)

libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc42" % "1.2.10.1009"
```

Let's also include [`Slick` dependencies](http://slick.lightbend.com/download/):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"          % "3.2.3",
  "org.slf4j"          %  "slf4j-nop"      % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.3"
)
```

One way to [configure the connection with `Slick`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/database.html) consists in using a `typesafe config`. Let's create `application.conf` in `src/main/resources/` with your `Redhsift` settings:

```
my_redshift {
  url = "jdbc:redshift://examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev"
  user = my_user
  password = my_password
  driver = com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

And we can finally load this configuration from Scala as such (`my_redshift` is the root you've chosen in the typesafe config):

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

val db: Database = Database.forConfig("my_redshift")
```

Comment: Cool! have you found any problem yet? I'm working on the same stuff right now.